# How do I make my filewriter write from the beginning not the most recent?

Tags: java, arrays, save

My project requires me to create a save button that when pressed, will write the name of the images(stickers) and their coordinates to save.txt. It writes to the save.txt but will only write the most recent image. I understand why it is doing that but not how to fix it. It is doing that because every time I place an image, it increments the integer "image". And when I press save, it writes the name and coordinates of "image". So it will write the most recent one. Please help me make it write it from the beginning. This is the save portion of my code.

```
else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){
            if (arraysticker[image] != null){
                String name;
                int x,y;
                name = sticker.getname();
                x = sticker.getx();
                y = sticker.gety();
                fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
            }
        }
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
    System.out.println("saved");
}
```

Here is my entire code if you need it. The only thing missing is me placing the initial images.

```
    sticker arrayhat = new sticker (20, "hat.png");
    sticker arrayblunt = new sticker (20, "blunt.png");
    sticker arraydealwithit = new sticker (20, "dealwithit.png");
    sticker arrayweed = new sticker (20, "weed.png");

    int image = -1;//declares an integer variable named image
    //creates a boolean variable and sets it to false
    boolean hatSoundPlay = false;
    boolean bluntSoundPlay = false;
    boolean dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
    boolean weedSoundPlay = false;


    while (true){//while it is true
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){//if left button is released
        int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse(); //get x coordinates
        int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse();//get y coordinates

            if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if hat is in the x and y coordinates
                bluntSoundPlay = false; //turn all sounds false
                weedSoundPlay = false; 
                dealwithitSoundPlay = false; 
                if (!hatSoundPlay) { //if hatsound not play
                    hatsound.play(); //hatsound will play
                    hatSoundPlay = true; //hat sound is now true    
                }
            }
            else if(bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if blunt is in the x and y coordinates
                hatSoundPlay = false;//turn all sounds false
                weedSoundPlay = false;
                dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
                if (!bluntSoundPlay) {//if bluntsound not play
                    bluntsound.play(); //then bluntsound will play
                    bluntSoundPlay = true; //bluntSoundPLay is now assigned to true
                }
            }
            else if(dealwithitPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if dealwithit is in the x and y coordinates
                hatSoundPlay = false;//turn all sounds false
                bluntSoundPlay = false;
                weedSoundPlay = false;
                if (!dealwithitSoundPlay) {//if dealwithitsound not play
                    dealwithitsound.play(); //then dealwithitsound will pay
                    dealwithitSoundPlay = true; //dealwithitSoundPlay is assigned as true
                }
            }
            else if(weedPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if weed is in the x and y coordinates
                dealwithitSoundPlay = false;//turn all sounds false
                hatSoundPlay = false;
                bluntSoundPlay = false;
                if (!weedSoundPlay) {//if weedsound not play
                    weedsound.play(); //then weedsound will play
                    weedSoundPlay = true; //sets the varialbe weedSoundPlay to true
                } 
            }


            else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
                    && !loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !clearPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
                    && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                if (hatSoundPlay){ //if hatSoundPlay is true
                    hatsound.play(); //and a hatsound will play
                    sticker sticker1 = new sticker();//creates a new sticker1
                    sticker1.arraysticker(hatPicture, "hat.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker1;//puts sticker 1 into the array

                } else if (bluntSoundPlay){ //else if bluntSound is true
                    bluntsound.play(); //and blunt sound will play
                    sticker sticker2 = new sticker();
                    sticker2.arraysticker(bluntPicture, "blunt.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker2;//puts sticker 2 into the array

                }else if (dealwithitSoundPlay){ //if dealwithitsound is true
                    dealwithitsound.play(); //dealwithitsound will play
                    sticker sticker3 = new sticker();
                    sticker3.arraysticker(dealwithitPicture, "dealwithit.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker3;//puts sticker 3 into the array

                }else if (weedSoundPlay){ //if weedsound is true
                    weedsound.play(); //weedsound will also play
                    sticker sticker4 = new sticker();
                    sticker4.arraysticker(weedPicture, "weed.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker4;//puts sticker 4 into the array
                }
            }
            else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){
                    if (arraysticker[image] != null){
                        String name;
                        int x,y;
                        name = sticker.getname();
                        x = sticker.getx();
                        y = sticker.gety();
                        fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
                    }
                }
                fw.flush();
                fw.close();
                System.out.println("saved");
            }
        //  else if (loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
            //  Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File ("save.txt"));
            //  for (int i = 0; i < arraysticker.length; i++){
                //  hatPicture.removeImage;
                //}
            //}
            }
        EZ.refreshScreen();     
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for-loop` is using the wrong `index` value...

```
for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){
    if (arraysticker[image] != null){
```

You're also not accessing the values from the `arraysticker`, it should probably be

```
for (int i = 0; image < arraysticker.length; i++){
    if (arraysticker[i] != null){
        String name;
        int x,y;
        name = arraysticker[i].getname();
        x = arraysticker[i].getx();
        y = arraysticker[i].gety();
        fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
    }
```

You should also have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for better ways to manage your resources and ensure that they are closed properly

Comment: If i use i < i, won't it not run at all? Because there is no way i will be less than i. Or am I not understanding it? Sorry this is my first semester programming.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference though as he is not using the array index to retrieve the image name or coordinates. Also, i believe you meant i<image in your suggested answer. i < i and loop would never execute :)

Comment: @user5329697 :P Thanks, was copy pasting stuff all around the place.

Comment: @justcurious I think it might be time for a caffeine break

Comment: I tried your solution but it is still not working. I think it is because by the time I click save, I already have like 10+ stickers. so image will never be less than i? That is what i think is happening. because nothing is being written in the save.txt

Comment: Sorry, the second example should be something more like `for (int i = 0; image < arraysticker.length; i++){`, may brain has already left the building for the evening